# How do I dismiss the "Drop HAR files here" box in Chrome network panel?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My Chrome console's network panel has become unusable today because it keeps getting overlaid with a drag/drop UI for HAR files. *How do I dismiss it, or turn this feature off?* Never encountered this behavior until today. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

One way to get out of this state is by closing Chrome's developer tools window and opening it again (e.g., F12 twice with focus on Chrome). The problem is this clears any info you may have accumulated in the Network panel.

A better way that does not have this problem is to drag a file (any file) over it and just make sure to drag it off the window not too fast. At that point you can cancel the drag (with the escape key or any other way).

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I just can't believe that this is still happening after almost a year. I mean, it happened to me a couple of times, but I didn't know what triggered that "Drop HAR" in the first place. Secondly, why can't just they make the "Esc" simply dismiss it.

Answer (score 10):

From your desktop, drag a small empty text file to the HAR popover window. This will crash in the console, the HAR popover will be dismissed, **and your network state will be preserved**. Then you can get back to doing what you were doing.

Comment: Interesting, the other answer is actually better, but Google pushed your answer into its feed. Both answer are good, anyways.